# PHP Codeigniter Integrar web service

Tags: php, codeigniter

Estoy integrando la libreria de `CodeIgniter Rest Server`, pero no me funciona, alguien podría orientarme correctamente, solo he copiado los archivos que indican en https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver, pero no funciona aun.

Copie los archivos `application/libraries/Format.php` y `application/libraries/REST_Controller.php` dentro de la carpeta `libraries` de mi proyecto.

Tambien copie el archivo `application/config/rest.php` dentro de mi carpeta `config`.

Luego cree el controlador Restserver:

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
use Restserver\Libraries\REST_Controller;

class Restserver extends REST_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }
}
```

Despues agregue el metodo para listar los productos:

```
public function products_get() {
    $this->load->model('products_model');
    $this->response($this->products_model>getproducts());
}
```

Pero al cargar la pagina, me sale error 500.

Comment: Hola bienvenido, debes mejorar la pregunta, que erro exactamente te arroja?, como has integrado los archivos de la librería? y mostrar algo de código relacionado, yo la uso y va de lujo.

Comment: ¿Porque haces un `$this->load->database();` dentro del controlador?

Comment: hola!, solo sigo los pasos del tutorial, la verdad recien me estoy familiarizando con el framework :(